# How to put Peewee ORM inside a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, orm, peewee

Is it possible to run the Peewee ORM fully inside one class? The simplest example from Peewee looks like this:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

class Person(Model):
    name = CharField()
    birthday = DateField()

    class Meta:
        database = db # This model uses the "people.db" database.
```

But I want to capsule everything (even further methods for loading and saving) inside a class. My failed code currently looks like this:

```
from peewee import *

class Database():
    def __init__(self, DatabaseFile = 'test.sqlite'):
        self.db = SqliteDatabase('people.db')

    class Person(self, Model):
        name = CharField()
        birthday = DateField()

        class Meta:
            database = self.db 
    
    # def put(self, data):...
    # def get(self, data):...

    # def CloseDatabase(self):
    #  self.db.close()
```

But this fires an error that self in class Meta is not defined. I am a bit lost at the moment how to solve this so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to parameterize the `database` attribute, I'd suggest taking a look here http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration